# passing workbook from command button vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question about something which is confusing me in VBA. I have a command button, which when clicked I want to set a variable = to a workbook object, then pass this object to another sub. I cannot work out why I can't pass it to the sub, I can't see why what I'm doing doesn't work. Code as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Workbooks.Open Filename:=TextBox1.Text
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

CreateChart wb
End Sub

Sub CreateChart(ByRef wb As Workbook)
'PURPOSE: Create a chart (chart dimensions are not required)

Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As Object

'Your data range for the chart
  Set rng = wb.ActiveSheet.Range("A24:A27")

'Create a chart
  Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2

'Give chart some data
  cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng

'Determine the chart type
  cht.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

End Sub
```

NB I have found a workaround which is to set the workbook within another sub, but would like to understand why it doesn't work this way. Please can anyone offer advice?

Thankyou.

Comment: Could you describe "doesn't work"?

Comment: Sorry. It gives the error: ByRef argument type mismatch

Comment: Did you try to declare `wb` in `Private Sub CommandButton2` first? As in `Dim wb As Workbook`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `CommandButton2_Click()` you don't declare `wb`. So it's a Variant data type. This isn't compatible to `ByRef wb As Workbook`.

So add

```
Dim wb As Workbook
```

and to avoid further errors like this, put [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module.

It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time. 
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor.

**Edit**: Demo

```
'Option Explicit

Sub Demo_Fail()
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    CreateChart wb      ' Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch
End Sub

Sub Demo_Success()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    CreateChart wb
End Sub

Sub CreateChart(ByRef wb As Workbook)
    Debug.Print wb.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou, this helps my understanding. Just found it weird as I was able to use the exact same code but in a sub that wasn't the button click and it worked...

Answer (score 1):

It's because you don't declare explicitly `wb` variable, so it's assumed implicitly as being of `Variant` type, while `CreateChart` accepts a `Workbook` type parameter

use:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook ' declare wb of Workbook type

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=TextBox1.Text
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    CreateChart wb
End Sub
```

but you can even shorten that down to:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()        
    CreateChart Workbooks.Open(Filename:=TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```